# SQL query to SELECT all rows that match only a specific condition

Tags: sql, sqlite, relational-division

I'm taking Stanford's online database course and am stuck on an exercise. [Here is the database](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/DB/SQL/asset/socialdata.html). The question is:

> Find names and grades of students who only have friends in the same grade.

Here is my attempt:

```
/* Select all highschoolers and their grades... */
SELECT h1.name, h1.grade
FROM Highschooler h1

/* ...where their grades are equal to all their friends' grades */
WHERE h1.grade = ALL(

  /* Select friends' grades */
  SELECT h2.grade
  FROM Highschooler h2
    JOIN Friend f
      ON f.ID1 = h1.ID
      AND f.ID2 = h2.ID
);
```

And I get this error:

> Query failed to execute: near 'ALL': syntax error

I've checked my SQL with an [online syntax checker](https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/), and it passes. What am I missing?

Comment: Is this SQL Server?  Or mysql?  You don't specify a DBMS..  I would actually replace ALL with IN or similar construct.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @Leptonator Exactly. Be carefull, there are different dialects of sql, so if you are following examples on the internet or books, be sure you are using the same dtb software.

Comment: @Leptonator his syntax checker is mysql.

Comment: Added the relational division tag. (Hint: you can rewite the condition as "students who *dont* have friends in *other* grades (but do have some friends)"

Comment: @wildplasser actually, clarification is needed if people with no friends should be included

Comment: @Leptonator, the dialect is SQLite. I didn't realize there was that much variance; I'll look into a SQLite validator.

Comment: @wildplasser, according to my notes, SQLite does not support `ANY` or `ALL`. I've used your hint to write the correct query.

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep it simple and standard, running across any sql flavor? You can get away with joins only.

```
select name, grade
from Highschooler h1
inner join friends f 
    on f.id1=h1.id
inner join Highschooler h2 
    on h2.id=f.id2
group by 1,2
having 
sum(case when h1.grade=h2.grade then 1 else 0 end) = count(*) -- nr of friends with same grade equals total nr of friends.
```

Comment: I think he is learning so he wants to use 'All' even if it is not the best and most efficient way to solve the problem.

Comment: I've been doing SQL for more than 25 years, haven't used `ALL` even once.

Comment: @Divisadero I will add the all. My gripe about the original example is the joins within subquery, which are a PITA to read and maintain irl

Comment: and yes, upvote for never using all - it not necessary, there is always a better, more readable way to do it using standard sql, that can be maintained by anyone with knowledge of any sql flavor.

Comment: This query doesn't execute for me, I think because you have a `HAVING` without a `GROUP BY`.